# Wireless and bluetooth drivers for 14.04 lts

Tags: 14.04, wireless, bluetooth, hp

My notebook is having ubuntu 14.04 LTS running on HP Pavillion 15-n011TU. I need the wireless and bluetooth drivers for that. Anybody could possibly send those drivers.

Thank you.

The outputs:
1) lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:197c]
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 08)
```

2)lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0781:5583 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0e8d:763e MediaTek Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05c8:0361 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co
```

., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [no Wi-Fi on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Asus notebook with MEDIATEK MT7630e](http://askubuntu.com/questions/676390/no-wi-fi-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-asus-notebook-with-mediatek-mt7630e)

Answer (score -1):

just connect the Ethernet cable (Broadband). open Additional Drivers option (you can search it on Ubuntu search) on Ubuntu 14.04 and once you click on Additional Drivers it will start searching the missing drivers and show you the drivers what you want once you activate that restart the system. thank you i hope this will help you