# no Wi-Fi on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Asus notebook with MEDIATEK MT7630e

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet

I'm new to Ubuntu. I installed it today, but the first thing I encounter is that I can only connect to the Internet through wifi. 
Can someone help me?

iwconfig result :

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM     Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5289 (rev 01)
04:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)
```

lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e074]
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:5289] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Can you edit in the output of `lspci`?

Comment: Hi. Please provide the results of lscpi -nnk | grep 0280 -A2

Comment: done, hope it helps, ty

Comment: Please specify what does not work ethernet or wifi?

Comment: @Pilot6 wifi is not working

Comment: Hm the wireless adapter is recognized. Maybe it's turned on by key combinations, often Function(fn)+ F5. Examine your keyboard for signs of this.

Comment: Please see this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/504718/wlan0-not-showing-up-mediatek-corp-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wireless

Comment: @Wildcard i have the key, but with fn +f2 nothing happn

Comment: @Pilot6 's link suggests it's a bug with that adapter. Assume thats correct and try to install that driver manually to see if it helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377050/how-do-i-get-a-mediatek-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wi-fi-adapter-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same wireless chip (and very similiar laptop); wireless never worked out-of-the-box both in Trusty and in Vivid; this is how I've always installed it:

1. Download the drivers for the wireless chip from [here](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1796);
2. Open Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>;
3. Run `cd ~/Downloads; unzip MT7630E-release.zip; cd MT7630E-release; sudo bash install`

If the driver is installed to an UEFI managed system, Secure Boot should be disabled in UEFI settings to get the module loaded.

Comment: DUDE U ARE A GOD, SO MUCH TANK YOU

Comment: A good one. +1.

Comment: @Lancilnove You're welcome :) I've been struggling as well the first time because the original drivers from MediaTek won't compile on every kernel without some modifications. Luckily the guy who posted the tutorial did the job for us :)