# How can I install MEDIATEK 7630e?

Tags: wireless, drivers, mediatek

My brand new ASUS computer does not seem to find a driver to make MEDIATEK MT7630e work? I've tried [this tutorial](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1796).

The driver then worked but the computer did not shut down anymore.

It seems to be a well-know problem that has not been fixed. Really? Never had a single unsolved problem with Ubuntu before.

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 10
       serial: 1c:b7:2c:8e:e3:11
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.1.107 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:47 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7104000-f7104fff memory:f7100000-f7103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7000000-f70fffff



00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Camarillo Device (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter

0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Apologize, I was too fast. Which model do you have exactly? The solution in the link worked for me on an ASUS F552C (which as far as I understand is either a variant of the X550CL or the X550CL sold with a different name in my country).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/676390/no-wi-fi-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-asus-notebook-with-mediatek-mt7630e

Comment: @Pilot6 I voted to close as well at first, but it seems that the problem is that OP can't shutdown after having done that.

Comment: Yes, quite. I've tried again: wifi works but the computer (ASUS X555LA) does not shut down anymore.