# Ubuntu freezes when connecting to Wifi hotspot

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, mediatek

When ever I try to connect to WIFI hotspot, ubuntu freezes.
By hotspot I mean wifi network where you first connect to the network without password then enter it in a dedicated page of a web browser.
By freeze I mean that the only action I can do is alt+sys+REISUB

I can connect to my wifi at home without any issue, or to the wifi of my smartphone when sharing connection. For instance command iwconfig result in :

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"AndroidAP"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 02:1A:11:F5:9B:A7
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=62 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:2  Invalid misc:72   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I have Ubuntu 14.04.
Here is my network controller

```
~$ lspci | grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
```

I installed Mediatek MT7630E Combo Linux Driver

I tried to connect via command line but ubuntu freezes after :

```
~$ iwconfig wlan0 essid NETWORK_ID
```

No specific logs.

I can give more information if needed as I have the results from [this script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205).

I tried to google this but without much result.

Does someone knows where it comes from ?
if you want me to retrieve some specific info on my system, explain me how to get it: I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no Wi-Fi on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Asus notebook with MEDIATEK MT7630e](http://askubuntu.com/questions/676390/no-wi-fi-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-asus-notebook-with-mediatek-mt7630e)

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks for you comment. I have not the same issue : I have installed the proper driver, wlan0 appears in iwconfig, and I can connect to some wifi. Just in case I tried to install the drivers mentioned your link, the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to install different drivers without success.

Moving from ubuntu 14.04 to 15.10 and installing latest drivers (from [here](https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E)) solved the issue.

FYI moving to 15.10 may trigger some [issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689417/ubuntu-15-10-and-wifi-mt7630e-cant-work-asus-transformer-tp300la) (it was not the case for me)