# Ubuntu 15.10 and Wifi MT7630e can't work (Asus transformer tp300la)

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, 15.10

With Ubuntu 15.04 out the internal Wifi card MT7630E can't work.
I download the same drivers from GitHub “MT7630-master” (worked in 15.04), but can't work on 15.10 with Kernel 4.2

I tried to compile the drivers but the error is related to

```
Linux-headers-4.2.0.16-generic
function rt2x00mac_configure_filter
FIF_PROMISC_IN_BSS undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I'm not a code hacker but looks something changed in the Kernel source, needed for this driver. Anybody could help with this?

Comment: I am facing the same problem

Comment: Are you on the most recent version of the [`release` branch](https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E/commits/release)? There was [an update for compatibility with kernel v4.2](https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E/commit/9aaa953c8331e3c3d36740a81eb0c7fa0ecc1655) a week ago. Give me a ping about the outcome, please, so I can convert this comment into an answer on success!

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by David Foerster in the 1st commet worked for me. I'm ussing an Asus n750 with the MT7630 chipset. I followed his recomendation so: I went to the proposed link: https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E/tree/e7130a42f8198cbf503a5a307175073c078bf340

Then I downloaded and unpacked the zipped file I opened a terminal and cd to the unpacked folder. In the terminal I directly wrote the code that are in the install file:

```
make
make install
sudo modprobe mt7630e
sudo modprobe mt76xx
```

and in that moment the wifi started to work. Thaks to Neurobin for such a fantastic job and thanks to David Foerster for the advice.