# No wifi internet connection on ubuntu 14.04 (dual boot with windows 8.1)

Tags: 14.04, networking, dual-boot, windows-8, internet

I have just installed ubuntu 14.04 on dual boot with windows 8.1 but ubuntu won't connect to wifi. I am using ASUS G771JM and here is the output of lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net' on terminal.

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e074]
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:5287] (rev 01)
--
04:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no Wi-Fi on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Asus notebook with MEDIATEK MT7630e](http://askubuntu.com/questions/676390/no-wi-fi-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-asus-notebook-with-mediatek-mt7630e)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377050/how-do-i-get-a-mediatek-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wi-fi-adapter-working)

Answer (score 0):

You might try to enable Additional Drivers in System settings > Software and update. If your card needs additional driver to operate properly, then you have to install it. The installation might need temporary wired internet connection to download the necessary packages.

Comment: This won't work for this adapter.